# Object evaluating in java

Tags: java, evaluation

I don't understand, why Java acts the way it does.

I have two classes,

Class A:

```
public class A {
  public String s = null;

  public A(int s) {
    this.s = "a";
  }

  public A(String s) {
    this.s = "b";
  }

  public int f(A p) {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends A {
  public String s = "c";
  public B() {
    super(null);
  }
  public B (String s) {
    this (0);
    this . s = s ;
  }
  public B (int x) {
    super ("d");
  this . s = this . s + x ;
  }
  public int f (A p) {
    return 3;
  }
  public int f(B p) {
    return 4;
}
```

If I know have my main class, in which I run the following code:

```java
public class Test {
  Public static main(String[] args) {
    B b1 = new B("g");
    A ab = new B(6);
    System.out.println(ab.f(b1));
  }
}
```

Why am I getting `3` as an result, and not `2` or `4`, like I would expect?
Normally I would assume, if I run the method f of the object ab, and give f the object b1 as a parameter, it would either return `2`, not compile (since the only method f in Class A uses an Object A and not an Object B) or it would look for another method f in Class B, that uses an Object B as a parameter and would execute that, in which case the program should return `4`.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "Runtime Polymorphism".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant statement

```
ab.f(b1)
```

The fact that you are passing the object reference `b1` to the method is irrelevant because none of these methods are doing anything with the parameters being passed. The question here is should calling `f()` return 3 or 2? It will return 3 because are creating an instance of *B* (`A ab = new B(6);`) and this class *B* overrode the `f()` method.

### What is the impact of `A ab = new B(6);`?

When you instantiate objects using the superclass to the right of the assignment symbol `=`, ***you are actually widening the type of the object created*** (Making an object of a subclass into an object of a superclass). If the subclass have new methods, those methods will be inaccessible to this object. Only methods declared in the superclass are accessible and, through polymorphism, overridden methods are accessible as well (as was already demonstrated by the example above). However, if we were to add a new method to class *B*

```
public void newMethod() {
    System.out.println("new method");
}
```

and modified the `Test` class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b1 = new B("g");
        A ab = new B(6);
        System.out.println(ab.f(b1));
        ab.newMethod(); // compile error
        b1.newMethod();
    }
}
```

`newMethod` will be inaccessible to instance `ab` but not to `b1`. For this reason, the method `f(B p)` is inaccessible for `ab`, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: The Problem with that, is, it isn't irrelevant at all, since I'm specifically asked in my exam to evaluate this expression ^^'

Comment: @Daerker it's irrelevant because nothing is done with that parameter. The answer won't change if, for instance, you pass `null` to the method. Do you understand?

Comment: Of course it matters if I pass f() with either b1, null or anything else. After all I'm overloading the method f in Class B. I understand that nothing happens with the parameter, but it still needs it, so java can differenciate which method of f it should choose

Comment: @Daerker you win. LOL  Look, you have to take my word for it. The reason why exams do stuff like that is to confuse you a bit and make you think. The question is what the call to `f()` should return. Since the parameter has no bearing in the result, it is irrelevant and thus, you can discard it as part of your analysis. But what do I know?

Comment: It clears up things up a bit more, however, my post got edited and a bit cropped, so what you can't know is that this code above (except the main-class) is provided by an old exam from 2020, so sadly I can't change any of the code. 
My question remains tho (and for simplicitys sake, let us ignore method f() of Class A).
If I invoke f(b1) (where b1 has the type B),  why does Java choose f(A p) over f(B p), although I'm calling the function with a parameter of the type B?

Comment: @Daerker because the method is overridden by the subclass. When a call to a method is made, the JVM looks for the appropriate method to call from the most concrete class (the bottom-most subclass) all the way up the hierarchy tree. In this case, the first match was the overridden method, so the JVM calls that one.

Comment: But in this case I have two methods f() in my subclass B (and a third on in the Superclass A), to which `f(B p)` is the more concrete one, but still Java chooses the less concrete Method `f(A p)` over `f(B p)` and I just can't get it in my head as to why Java does that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241802/discussion-between-hfontanez-and-daerker).

Comment: @Daerker long story short, for the call to `f()` to output 4, both the object invoking the method AND the parameter need to be an instance of class `B`. So, for that to work you would need to do this: `System.out.println(b1.f(b1));` Because it is in class `B1` where the `f(B p)` method exist. Even if you do `System.out.println(b1.f(ab));` will output 3 because, although `ab` was created as `new B()`, the type was widened to `A` by the part left of the assignment operator (the variable declaration).

Answer (score 0):

I think it calls your f method in class B that returns 3 because, even though b1 is of class B, class B is a subclass of A.  Since :

```
public int f (A p) {
   return 3;
}
```

comes before the other f method, it checks that first.  It says is b1 of type A? And the answer is yes, because all Bs are As. So it uses that function, returns 3 and completes the method call.

Comment: That would make sense, but wouldn't Java first check, if there's a "perfect fitting" answer before implicitly assuming that b1 is of type A? Java does implicitly change types on numbers (byte -> short -> int -> long) depending if it hasn't found a fitting method and just change a short to an int to see if that would fit, but only if it had checked all methods beforehand

Comment: No, because the way it is written it reaches the line with the first definition of f(A p) , checks it and says, "yes, this works." and executes the return.  Once a return is executed, the method is done.

Comment: Try switching the order of the method definitions and see what happens.

Comment: "_No, because the way it is written it reaches the line with the first definition of f(A p) , checks it and says, "yes, this works." and executes the return._" - this is not quite what is happening here. The method `f(B p)` is "erased" because of type widening. For the variable `ab`, that method simply does not exist in a matter of speaking.

Comment: Right- it's always going to execute the first one, if it's going to execute any.